# SinonJS Spy Cannot Restore Read Only Method/Property of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

It gives me `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'get' of object '#<Config>'`.

I'm using `mocha 8.0.1`, `chai 4.2.0`, `sinon 9.0.2` for Unit Testing.

I'm spying on a method in the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) npm package.

Here's how I spy the `get` method:

```
...
before(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      configStub = sandbox.spy(config, 'get');
});

after(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
});

it('should something', async () => {
      console.log('Just logging');

      config.get('LOG.LEVEL'); // just to show the point. if I remove this line, it doesn't throw the error
});
...
```

What happens is, if I run `config`'s `get` method somewhere during the test, it can not be restored by spy. It throws that read-only property error. But when the `config.get` function is never called, it doesn't throw that error (I don't understand why not). For `stub` there's no problem, it can restore just fine.

But the reason I'm using `spy` is because I want `config.get` to work like it normally does while I'm testing my module/function that's using it, I just want to spy on it. And I also need to be able to restore it after this test suite. I spy on it because I need to test that it's being called by my module/function with some specific parameters.

How do I spy on a **read-only** property/method, allow my module/function to use it like it normally does, and then restore it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS` environment variable to `true` for the test run.
In this way `config.get` invocation will not freeze the config which should resolve the issue.

You can find the env var description in the documentation:

https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#allow_config_mutations